# How to make a query from a dictionary keyed by column value, the most concise, the better in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlalchemy

I have a table of assets with categories and status values:

| asset id. | asset category | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | auto | 0 |
| 2 | auto | 50 |
| 3 | auto | 60 |
| 4 | bike | 30 |
| 5 | bike | 14 |
| 6 | plane | 16 |

I'd like to obtain a dict from it:

```
{
 auto: {not_ok: 1, to_watch: 0, ok: 2},
 bike: {not_ok: 0, to_watch: 1, ok: 1},
 plane:{not_ok: 0, to_watch: 0, ok: 1}
}
```

where `not_ok`, `to_watch`, and `ok` are the count of each category when status falls in an interval defined as:
interval = np.linspace(0, `max_status_by_category` , 4).tolist().
For example, interval_auto = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0], interval_bike = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0] and so on:

```
interval[0]<= not_ok <= interval[1]
interval[1]< to_watch <= interval[2]
interval[2]<   ok <= interval[3]
```

For the moment, what I do is to obtain the maximum status per category:

```
q_c = session.query(Assets.asset_category, func.count(Assets.asset_category),
                    func.max(Assets.asset_state)
                    ).group_by(Assets.asset_category).all()
```

Which gives me the name of categories, the number of assets of each category and the maximum status per category.
Then I loop over the list I just obtained, making the intervals per category and requesting the number of `ok`, `to_watch`,..... Like:

```
q_status = session.query(Assets.asset_category, func.count(Assets.asset_category),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state >= interval[0], Assets.asset_state <= interval[1]), False)),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state > interval[1], Assets.asset_state <= interval[2]), False)),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state > interval[2], Assets.asset_state <= interval[3]), False)),
           ) \
 .group_by(Assets.asset_category).all()
```

Although this works, I'd like to make it more compact and concise. For example:

- Is there a way to make the intervals on the fly and obtain the status on a single query??
- Let's say I can't make the intervals on the fly, but I can obtain them like before:

```
interval = {
auto: [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0],
bike: [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0],
plane: [0.0, 5.333333333333333, 10.666666666666666, 16.0]
}
```

Can we make the query to access this dictionary while the query runs? I mean, something like this:

```
q_status = session.query(Assets.asset_category, func.count(Assets.asset_category),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state >= interval[Assets.asset_category][0], Assets.asset_state <= interval[Assets.asset_category][1]), False)),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state > interval[Assets.asset_category][1], Assets.asset_state <= interval[Assets.asset_category][2]), False)),
          func.count(func.nullif(and_(Assets.asset_state > interval[Assets.asset_category][2], Assets.asset_state <= interval[Assets.asset_category][3]), False)),
           ) \
 .group_by(Assets.asset_category).all()
```

Which of course doesn't work. I am open to any idea to make this compact and if possible more performant.

Comment: In the end I used Pandas read_sql. Manipulations are way easier and more performant than regular Python lists obtained from sqlalchemy.